# haskell create list from lists with different attributes

Tags: list, haskell

Yes this is a uni assignment question, so please do not just give me the answer, I need to be able to learn what it is and how to do it, (mostly because there are further questions and I need to develop an understanding of the Haskell language to do them!

## THE QUESTION:

```
join :: Eq a => [(a,b)] -> [(a,c)] -> [(a,b,c)].
```

join takes two lists of pairs, and returns a single list of triples. A triple
is generated only when there exists a member of both argument lists
that have the same first element. The list elements are not sorted. This
is the same semantics as the relational algebra natural join operation.

For example:

```
join [(2,"S"),(1,"J")] [(2,True),(3,False)]) 
    Should produce the output [(2,"S",True)]
join [(2,"S"),(1,"J")] [(2,1),(2,2),(3,4)])
    Should produce the output [(2,"S",1),(2,"S",2)]
```

## My problem

My main problem is trying to figure out how to create a new list from the 2 lists that are input, which have different attributes.

### What I have so far:

```
join :: Eq a => [(a,b)] -> [(a,c)] -> [(a,b,c)]
join xs     []     = xs
join []     ys     = ys
join (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x ++ snd(head[x]) ++ snd(head[y]) ++ []) join xs ys
```

## The resulting error:

```
Type error in explicitly typed binding
*** Term           : merge
*** Type           : [(a,b)] -> [(a,c)] -> [(a,b)]
*** Does not match : [(a,b)] -> [(a,c)] -> [(a,b,c)]
```

## Other notes:

I have tried several variations of the (x ++ snd(head[x]) ++ snd(head[y]) ++ []) section of code, with the results being mostly the same or simular error message!

Answer (score 1):

Your types do not match

```
join :: Eq a => [(a,b)] -> [(a,c)] -> [(a,b,c)]
join xs     []     = xs
join []     ys     = ys
                 --  ^^^^   three different types involved!
```

`xs` and `ys` has type `[(a, b)]` and `[(a, c)]` then, they can not be the resultant type `[(a,b,c)]`.

You must to create your resultant data from `xs` and `ys`, something like

```
join ? ? = ... (a, b, c) ...
```

Can you figure that?

Tip: what is the body of

```
makeTuple :: (a, b) -> (a, c) -> (a, b, c)
                         --          ^  ^
                         --          :  |
                         --          :  +-- only one value exists you can put here
                         --          :
                         --          +····· only one value exists you can put here
```

the only two possible functions are

```
makeTuple (x1, y) (x2, z) = (x1, y, z)
```

and

```
makeTuple (x1, y) (x2, z) = (x2, y, z)
```

In the same way, your `join` must to preserve the resultant type.

From signature

```
join :: Eq a => [(a,b)] -> [(a,c)] -> [(a,b,c)]
```

you know type `a` is equatable and you know **nothing** about `b` and `c` types.

A simple way to do this is

```
join xs ys = [(xa, xb, yc) | (xa, xb) <- xs, (ya, yc) <- ys, xa == ya]
                                      --                     ^^^^^^^^
                                      --                 from `Eq a` constraint
```

Comment: Well that explains why, not matter what I try, it will not compile, trying to combine lists with different attributes. How would I find out what makeTuple is?

Comment: @user3633383 look at type signature, you take two tuples of types `(a, b)` and `(a, c)` then, It cannot be `(String, Bool)` and `(Int, Double)` since `String` type is different than `Int` type and, signature force to be `a` the same type on first and second tuples. You can replace each `a`, `b` and `c` into signature by any explicit types. In fact, the signature force to you to write only two possible bodies!!! :)

Comment: Going by the example usage:

    join [(2,"S"),(1,"J")] [(2,True),(3,False)]
        = [(2,"S",True)]
    join [(2,"S"),(1,"J")] [(2,1),(2,2),(3,4)]
        = [(2,"S",1),(2,"S",2)]

(int, char, bool)
But the second usage is (int, char, int)

Comment: Don't worry about explicit types, although second example is `(Int, String, Int)` really your function define the tuple `(a, b, c)` with first and third elements with different type. Finally, if is `makeTuple (x1, y) (x2, z)`, the only two valid bodies are `(x1, y, z)` and `(x2, y, z)` not exists any other possible function. Try to use type information to fix your `join` function. :)

Comment: 'makeTuple (a:b) (a:c) = (fst(head[a]), snd(head[b]), snd(head[c]))' produces an error **Repeated variable "a" in pattern** ?

Comment: Ouch! is not the same thing types than values, I'll update my response but I suggest to you learn Haskell basics. Lots of courage and good luck!

Comment: Wow, what a really simple way to do it (now that I see how it's done). I was close a few times in some of the things that I tried, but doubt I would have tried the end result. Thanks for all your help. Now I need to figure out how to extend it to add implementation of a Maybe data type for the third part of the triple. Cheers!